# can we create email accounts automatically on signup using php?

Tags: php, email

I have a sign up page in my site and i want to create an email account for any customer who use that form.

for ex: if a visitor come and enter the name **john** and my domain name is **ocata.com** than once he click on sign up, an email **john@ocata.com** will create automatically.

Is this even possible? my server is Godaddy vps server.
I am using this code

```
<?php
$cpuser = "cpanel_user_name";
$cppass = "cpanel_password";
$euser = "email_user_name";
$epass = "email_password";
$equota = "email_quota";
$domain = "domian.com";
$url = "http://".$cpuser.":".$cppass."@".$domain."2082/frontend/x3/mail    /doaddpop.html?email=".$euser."&domain=".$domain."&password=".$epass."&quota=".$equota;
if($cpanel = fopen($url, "r"))
{
echo "Success email creation.";
fclose($cpanel);
}
else
{
echo "Failed email creation.";
}
?>
```

It gives me the message , success email creation, but there is no email account created actually.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldnt even try to create e-mail addresses into cPanel.

If you have a database i would insert them into there and use the PHPMailer class to send it using a script. Call on the database and read all the available e-mail addresses into an array. Check to make sure each e-mail is valid. kick out all the bad ones. Then create a loop that goes through each e-mail address and sends the mail one at a time (to ensure all the TO addresses arent exposed).

All of the data in your script here is being passed over CLEARNET and is getting exposed verse just calling on a single script called createuser.php and sendmailtouser.php. From within the createuser.php script you can generate an e-mail address and ensure it isn't already taken within the db. if it is just increment the number.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i did not get you after save the email ids in db. what should i do with these ids? i mean is it possible to create these email accounts on server by writing a script? and not do it manually.

Comment: To get these email addresses you can write a basic HTML form that takes the users input. Once the form is submitted have a PHP script handle the POST requests (HTML form submit). The PHP script that handles the POST request can then insert the e-mail address into the DB after it has been has been verified and checked for duplicates.